# App was reviewed by instagram

Tags: instagram-api

My app was approved permissions by instagram team. However, Instagram api platform will deprecate in early 2020. My app will stop. Instagram team have any policy for this problem

Answer (score 0):

I guess we need to migrate to Graph API by then. And only business accounts would be supported after that. No APIs for other accounts. (somewhat similar to WeChat account types)

Comment: Did you get public_content approved?